# How to type Hindi in open office?

Tags: fonts, openoffice.org, ibus

i m using ubuntu 10.10. please tell me how to type in hindi fonts in open office word. please help

Answer (score 5):

Type the following in terminal.
`sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib ibus-gtk`

Now Goto **System>>Preferences>>Keyboard Input Methods** Or Type **ibus-setup** in terminal to start the daemon.After starting the daemon IBUS Preferences will be opened.

[image]
Select the Input Method tab and from the drop down Add Hindi language and click close.Now open open office word and you can start typing in Hindi by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again you can start typing in English.

**Typing in Open Office Word:**
[image]
You can toggle between both the languages by pressing **CTRL+SPACE**.

Comment: as usual, nice answer :) just one unrelated question, what theme is that?

Comment: @Kaustubh that's tropical theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable SCIM input method for this.

Here is an article in Ubuntu India site: http://www.ubuntu-in.info/wiki/IndicLangWithScim

Hope this will help.

Comment: Dead link. Please update the answer.