# how to type in indic language from English US keyboard

Tags: 11.10, fonts, libreoffice, desktop-environments, language-support

I opened libreoffice 3.0 (Ubuntu 11.10) and selected Lohit Hindi font
in the fonts selection column.
Downloaded the charachter map of English and Hindi keys as given here
http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/International_Language_Support_Guide/images/hindi.png

but when  I am typing in Hindi with my english keyboard there is no
Hindi word I still the english letters typed as
"kerasadsd".Which should not happen since Lohit Hindi font is selected
so I expected the correcponding key mapped Hindi characters to appear.
What mistake did I do in above?
I have US English keyboard only and I am using the same to type in Hindi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to type Hindi in open office?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15648/how-to-type-hindi-in-open-office)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a font is not enough. You need to have a proper input method also (keyboard layout).

Here is what you do: Dash - System Settings - Keyboard Layout - Layouts - Add (A small plus sign at the bottom left).

Add the one you are comfortable with.

Now, start Libreoffice, switch the keyboard layout (using the bar at the top in Gnome Shell) and you are ready to go.

Comment: My guess is you need the proper keyboard layout but you don't need an "input method". Input methods are used for entering languages like Chinese, Japanese and Korean.

Comment: Thanks deshmukh, I've been trying to get Sinhala working for a while now but never noticed the little keyboard symbol at the top of Gnome Shell.

Comment: @deshmukh this has increased my problem now I see an unwanted chinese language in ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/100684/unwanted-chinese-language-got-set-in-system-settings

Comment: Sure, I had not noticed earlier but I also have Chinese language at the top. I am sure there is a way to resolve it. But I do not know what it is.