# Unwanted Chinese language got set in system settings

Tags: 11.10, gnome, desktop-environments, language-support

I have made some changes in system settings, following suggestions by some users. However, this morning when I did a reboot I am unable to see English as my default language. My system is showing some Chinese characters which I do not understand.

All I wanted was to use Libre Office for a particular document in Hindi. What happened is  that even Gmail is opening in Chinese. The system settings folder and others are also opening in Chinese. I am unable to use the system now.

I have uploaded the snapshots here: please have a look.

- [Upon a reboot, I was asked to rename all folders](https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704405897276606450).
- [Gmail opening in Chinese](https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704406102859334402)
- This is how menu on my system looks: [half English and half Chinese](https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704407869479955202)

Notice that in the third snapshot the calendar and menu are appearing in Chinese.

I want the original US English menus and folder names back. I just wanted to type a document with Lohit Hindi font in Libre Office.

I use Ubuntu 11.10. I do not use Unity, only Gnome desktop. I installed
gnome-session-fallback a long time back and have been using that ever since.

How do I get back to all English submenus and English folder names? I have a US English Keyboard and I use only US English. This thing which is now somehow set is unwanted.

Comment: maybe try setting all entries in the file /etc/default/locale to en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @MichaelK I have uploaded a snapshot here that setting is already what you are saying but the problem still is there 
https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704438714062026210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed in files `/etc/environment`, `$HOME/.profile` following lines were present:

```
export LANGUAGE="zh_CN:en"
export LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
```

and in `/etc/default/locale` only US English line was present as you can see this snapshot:

[image]

I went to those files and deleted these extra lines of Chinese Language now I am able to resolve this problem and things are back on track.

However specially want to mention that `gnome-language-selector` did not help at all.

Sharing this for future archives hope this solution will help some one in future.

Answer (score 1):

edit your file

```
/etc/default/locale
```

in there change all settings to

> en_US.UTF-8

Comment: I have uploaded a snapshot here that setting is already what you are saying but the problem still is there 
https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704438714062026210

Comment: as per a suggestion here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918968
I had opened gnome-language-selector but I was stuck here in following steps
step 1 
https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704443014619612178
step 2 
https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704443092135311202

Comment: just click one of the buttons :-D

Comment: well I had clicked one of those buttons but there was no change upon even selecting english.

Answer (score 0):

I had my account mysteriously change to Chinese after an update today - this is 12.04.

The problem was in .pam_environment: I changed all zh_CN to en_GB and logged back in again.

I will note that when the pop-up thing says 'Oooh, you've changed your language, do you want to rename all your directories', just perhaps there should be a very obvious option 'Oh no, I didn't mean for that to be magically inflicted upon me by some weird configuration mistake, please keep my language settings as they were!'.

If there was one, I didn't notice it, so it's probably not obvious enough.