# Unwanted Asian Language set on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

On my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, unwanted Asian language (I cant tell which) is set. Odd thing is I kept choosing English US all along, but I still get this garbage mixed in the icon definitions, Firefox icon is messed up, other arent, then top-left most menu description is gone. I saw this post

[Unwanted Chinese language got set in system settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100684/unwanted-chinese-language-got-set-in-system-settings)

But the fix described there did not work for me. I looked in my .profile, .bashrc, /etc/profile, there are no language settings there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in /etc/default/locale I set this and it worked

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
```