# Ubuntu 17.10 is in French when I set English

Tags: language-support, system-language

I'd like to change the language of Ubuntu 17.10 to English (from French). I've changed it in the GNOME Settings:

[image]

And:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I've logged out and rebooted but everything is still in French (command line prompts and GNOME interface).

Any hint?

Comment: Also see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/100754/

Comment: I suspect that you previously set French manually somewhere, as in the answer @pomsky pointed at. Check out e.g. `~/.profile` and `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Yep, you were right, I had `export LC_CTYPE=fr_BE.UTF-8` and
`export LC_ALL=fr_BE.UTF-8` in my `.bashrc`. If you create an answer, I can mark it as the solution ;)

Comment: Great that you found the explanation. Please feel free to post an answer yourself - it's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comments on the question, I checked my `.bashrc` file and I still had some traces of a previously set locale:

```
export LC_CTYPE=fr_BE.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=fr_BE.UTF-8
```

Removing them solved the issue.