# Hindi keyboard not working properly in Ubuntu

Tags: language-support, input-language

I saw and followed the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages/165650#165650), but the Hindi didn't work properly, both in case of keyboard app (layout settings) and ibus.

Here's the problem (people who know Hindi will be in position to answer it):

Suppose I want to write my name ie Udayan - it start with the उ (spelt as 'u') but when I press u for writing उ what appears is ु (my name appears ुदायान). Similar is the case with starting words with अ, इ, ई, ऊ but आ works ( eg. आसम for Asam). Using the matras however, works fine: ie say k+u = कु (where 'u' is the matra).

Refer to [this document](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/I18N/Indic/HindiKeyboardLayouts#Itrans_Keyboard_Layout) for help.

Comment: Possibly keyboard layout issue..

Comment: People I accepted the answer that suited my requirements more but even the other one was correct and I would need to use that suggestion if I used that version of Hindi.Its really bad if u cant accept more than 1 answer when both are equally correct- do something moderators.

Comment: @UdayanSanyal: click on "meta" on the top, you can expose you concern to moderators there better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different Hindi keyboard mapping put different letters in different places. Which layout you choose is your personal preference and what you are used to.

In some keyboard layouts like "Phonetic" http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/I18N/Indic/HindiKeyboardLayouts#Phonetic_Keyboard_Layout उ is mapped to the ' (single quote, next to Enter) key.

I find Hindi-iTrans (in ibus) the most intuitive. iTrans is a bit more than simple mapping of letters to keys. It tries to make typing in Indian languages more intuitive. However, iTrans has it's own quirks and takes some time to get used to.

There is a [Bengali-iTrans](http://www.aczoom.com/itrans/html/beng/node4.html) ([Also see this page for yuktakshar](http://www.aczoom.com/itrans/html/beng/node5.html))in ibus as well. What I don't like about it is typing k will give you क् with the hasato. You have to type ka to get क. Sorry for the Hindi font, I am not at my Ubuntu computer at the moment. Another nice Bengali keyboard is "Prabhat". It is available both in ibus as well as normal keyboard layouts.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Check the keyboard layout*: if you are using Hindi Bolnagri keyboard layout, to print उ you need to press Alt+u and to print ऊ، Alt+Shift+u.

* Depending with DE you are using, getting to show the layout may differ:

- using KDE, I haven't found a way to show the keyboard layout;
- using Gnome Shell, you have an option to "show keyboard layout" when you right-click on the keyboard indicator;
- I don't know about Unity (please edit);
- I don't know about XFCE (please edit).

[image: bolnagri layout]

Comment: PS: I recommend the Bolnagri Layout because it matches the phonetic equivalent (except for retroflex ट, ठ, ड, ढ). Use the x-key to make compounds with the *vihara* `्` (क + ् + ष = क्ष)

Comment: i don't know my DE but to show layout I have to click on keyboard icon at upper right corner of screen and then click on "show layout chart"  By the way thanks for ur help.

Comment: I learned by looking through options and playing around. If you type "hindi" in the search field of this site, you will find answers like this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15648/how-to-type-hindi-in-open-office. About the *virāma* (not vihāra, sorry) and other aspects of the script, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari and http://www.omniglot.com/writing/devanagari.htm

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: THANKS dude the problem is solved only question is where did u find this-is there some page or file containing such information about using hindi font ,any set of guidelines or help files to download. Besides I dont get the "vihara ् (क + ् + ष = क्ष)" thing and the "retroflex ट, ठ, ड, ढ)."thing .

Comment: You cannot accept both. But you can upvote both.

Comment: thanks a lot .Sorry for I cant accept 2 answers(i didnt know that) urs was really really helpful but using Mr user's solution I find it easy.I really apologies to u

Comment: No need to apologise. I will survive even if you don't accept. I just mentioned it for the site's sake. Any answer you prefer will do: http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

> I saw and followed the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages/165650#165650), but the Hindi didn't
>   work properly, both in case of keyboard app (layout settings) and
>   ibus.
>
> Here's the problem (people who know Hindi will be in position to
>   answer it):
>
> Suppose I want to write my name ie Udayan - it start with the उ (spelt
>   as 'u') but when I press u for writing उ what appears is ु (my name
>   appears ुदायान). Similar is the case with starting words with अ, इ, ई,
>   ऊ but आ works ( eg. आसम for Asam). Using the matras however, works
>   fine: ie say k+u = कु (where 'u' is the matra).
>
> Refer to [this document](https://prowritingservice.com/) for help.

I had find on the net,maybe it will be help you
EDIT I should be more helpful here:

They are hidden and not dropped. If you open a terminal window and run this command:

Code:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
the Bolnagri layouts should be shown in the user interface again.